Flutter streaming with FFmpeg_flutter_kit not reaching server
I'm trying to stream my flutter screen to youtube using FFmpeg flutter kit. Everything seems fine but the output never reaches youtube server.

log in using Yt flutter package.

create a broadcast

create the livestream and bind it to the broadcast

get the ingestion address through LiveStreamItem.cdn.ingestionInfo.ingestionAddress

stream the frames saved through FFmpeg:
final String rtmpUrl = "ls.cdn.ingestionInfo.ingestionAddress"
final String command = '-re -i $framePath -c:v libx264 -f flv $rtmpUrl';
await FFmpegKit.execute(command);


But at the end I get errors like SESSION_NOT_FOUND, or the stream never reaches the server which keeps my broadcast as ready and not active so I can't go live.
I've tried using the ingestionAddress plus the streamName separated by a slash, I've tried the direct stream using rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/MY_API_KEY but none of that worked.
ERROR LOG:

I/flutter (19889): ffmpeg version n6.0 I/flutter (19889):  Copyright
(c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter
(19889):   built with Android (7155654, based on r399163b1) clang
version 11.0.5
(https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project
87f1315dfbea7c137aa2e6d362dbb457e388158d) I/flutter (19889):
configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android-
--sysroot=/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot
--prefix=/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg
--pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --ar=aarch64-linux-android-ar --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --ranlib=aarch64-linux-android-ranlib --strip=aarch64-linux-android-strip --nm=aarch64-linux-android-nm --extra-libs='-L/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib
-lndk_compat' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon I/flutter (19889):   libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100 I/flutter
(19889):   libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100 I/flutter (19889):
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100 I/flutter (19889):
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100 I/flutter (19889):
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100 I/flutter (19889):   libswscale
7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100 I/flutter (19889):   libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100 I/flutter (19889): Input #0, png_pipe, from
'/data/user/0/com.example.poc_stream/cache/frame.png': I/flutter
(19889):   Duration:  I/flutter (19889): N/A I/flutter (19889): ,
bitrate:  I/flutter (19889): N/A I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter
(19889):   Stream #0:0 I/flutter (19889): : Video: png, rgba(pc),
412x771 I/flutter (19889): ,  I/flutter (19889): 25 fps,  I/flutter
(19889): 25 tbr,  I/flutter (19889): 25 tbn I/flutter (19889):
E/flutter (19889): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(SESSION_NOT_FOUND, Session not
found., null, null) E/flutter (19889): #0
StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
(package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7) E/flutter
(19889): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18) E/flutter
(19889):  E/flutter (19889): #2
FFmpegKitFactory.mapToNullableSession
(package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/src/ffmpeg_kit_factory.dart:76:3)
E/flutter (19889):  E/flutter (19889): #3
FFmpegKitInitializer._processCompleteCallbackEvent.
(package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/src/ffmpeg_kit_flutter_initializer.dart:213:48)
E/flutter (19889):  E/flutter (19889):
I/flutter (19889): Stream mapping: I/flutter (19889):   Stream #0:0 ->
#0:0 I/flutter (19889):  (png (native) -> h264 (libx264)) I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889): Press [q] to stop, [?] for help I/flutter
(19889): [libx264 @ 0xb40000736398c190] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8
NEON I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb400007363a92e40] using cpu
capabilities: ARMv8 NEON I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @
0xb40000736398c190] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.0, 4:4:4,
8-bit I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb40000736398c190] 264 - core 164

H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2023 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3
deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0
deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6
lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
aq=1:1.00 I/flutter (19889): Output #0, flv, to
'rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/x7k6-grm1-z15w-tqb7-akrt': I/flutter
(19889):   Metadata: I/flutter (19889):     encoder         :
I/flutter (19889): Lavf60.3.100 I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889):
Stream #0:0 I/flutter (19889): : Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007),
yuv444p(tv, unknown/bt709/iec61966-2-1, progressive), 412x771, q=2-31
I/flutter (19889): ,  I/flutter (19889): 25 fps,  I/flutter (19889):
1k tbn I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889):     Metadata: I/flutter
(19889):       encoder         :  I/flutter (19889): Lavc60.3.100
libx264 I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889):     Side data:
I/flutter (19889):        I/flutter (19889): cpb:  I/flutter (19889):
bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0  I/flutter (19889):
vbv_delay: N/A I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889): Instance of
'Statistics' I/flutter (19889): frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=
0kB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A     I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @
0xb400007363a92e40] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.0, 4:4:4,
8-bit I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb400007363a92e40] 264 - core 164
H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2023 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3
deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0
deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6
lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
aq=1:1.00 I/flutter (19889): Output #0, flv, to
'rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/x7k6-grm1-z15w-tqb7-akrt': I/flutter
(19889):   Metadata: I/flutter (19889):     encoder         :
I/flutter (19889): Lavf60.3.100 I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889):
Stream #0:0 I/flutter (19889): : Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007),
yuv444p(tv, unknown/bt709/iec61966-2-1, progressive), 412x771, q=2-31
I/flutter (19889): ,  I/flutter (19889): 25 fps,  I/flutter (19889):
1k tbn I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889):     Metadata: I/flutter
(19889):       encoder         :  I/flutter (19889): Lavc60.3.100
libx264 I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889):     Side data:
I/flutter (19889):        I/flutter (19889): cpb:  I/flutter (19889):
bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0  I/flutter (19889):
vbv_delay: N/A I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889): Instance of
'Statistics' I/flutter (19889): frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=
0kB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A     I/flutter (19889): [flv @
0xb4000074238c1c30] Failed to update header with correct duration.
I/flutter (19889): [flv @ 0xb4000074238c1c30] Failed to update header
with correct filesize. I/flutter (19889): Instance of 'Statistics'
I/flutter (19889): frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=28.0 Lsize=       4kB
time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x     I/flutter (19889):
video:4kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB
muxing overhead:  I/flutter (19889): 8.895621% I/flutter (19889):
I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb40000736398c190] frame I:1     Avg
QP:14.17  size:  2957 I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @
0xb40000736398c190] mb I  I16..4:  1.4% 93.3%  5.3% I/flutter (19889):
[libx264 @ 0xb40000736398c190] 8x8 transform intra:93.3% I/flutter
(19889): [libx264 @ 0xb40000736398c190] coded y,u,v intra: 3.4% 1.4%
1.7% I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb40000736398c190] i16 v,h,dc,p: 78% 17%  6%  0% I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb40000736398c190] i8
v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36%  0% 64%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb40000736398c190] i4
v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 49% 21% 14%  1%  3%  4%  3%  2%  3%
I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb40000736398c190] kb/s:591.40
I/flutter (19889): ffmpeg version n6.0 I/flutter (19889):  Copyright
(c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter
(19889):   built with Android (7155654, based on r399163b1) clang
version 11.0.5
(https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project
87f1315dfbea7c137aa2e6d362dbb457e388158d) I/flutter (19889):
configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android-
--sysroot=/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot
--prefix=/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg
--pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --ar=aarch64-linux-android-ar --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --ranlib=aarch64-linux-android-ranlib --strip=aarch64-linux-android-strip --nm=aarch64-linux-android-nm --extra-libs='-L/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib
-lndk_compat' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon I/flutter (19889):   libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100 I/flutter
(19889):   libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100 I/flutter (19889):
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100 I/flutter (19889):
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100 I/flutter (19889):
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100 I/flutter (19889):   libswscale


1.100 /  7.  1.100 I/flutter (19889):   libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100 I/flutter (19889): [flv @ 0xb4000074238dac30] Failed to
update header with correct duration. I/flutter (19889): [flv @
0xb4000074238dac30] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
I/flutter (19889): Instance of 'Statistics' I/flutter (19889): frame=
1 fps=0.0 q=28.0 Lsize=       4kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=
0x     I/flutter (19889): video:4kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other
streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:  I/flutter (19889):
8.895621% I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889): Input #0, png_pipe, from '/data/user/0/com.example.poc_stream/cache/frame.png': I/flutter
(19889):   Duration:  I/flutter (19889): N/A I/flutter (19889): ,
bitrate:  I/flutter (19889): N/A I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter
(19889):   Stream #0:0 I/flutter (19889): : Video: png, rgba(pc),
412x771 I/flutter (19889): ,  I/flutter (19889): 25 fps,  I/flutter
(19889): 25 tbr,  I/flutter (19889): 25 tbn I/flutter (19889):
I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb400007363a92e40] frame I:1     Avg
QP:14.17  size:  2957 I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @
0xb400007363a92e40] mb I  I16..4:  1.4% 93.3%  5.3% I/flutter (19889):
[libx264 @ 0xb400007363a92e40] 8x8 transform intra:93.3% I/flutter
(19889): [libx264 @ 0xb400007363a92e40] coded y,u,v intra: 3.4% 1.4%
1.7% I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb400007363a92e40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 78% 17%  6%  0% I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb400007363a92e40] i8
v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36%  0% 64%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb400007363a92e40] i4
v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 49% 21% 14%  1%  3%  4%  3%  2%  3%
I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb400007363a92e40] kb/s:591.40
I/flutter (19889): ffmpeg version n6.0 I/flutter (19889):  Copyright
(c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter
(19889):   built with Android (7155654, based on r399163b1) clang
version 11.0.5
(https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project
87f1315dfbea7c137aa2e6d362dbb457e388158d) I/flutter (19889):
configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android-
--sysroot=/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot
--prefix=/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg
--pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --ar=aarch64-linux-android-ar --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --ranlib=aarch64-linux-android-ranlib --strip=aarch64-linux-android-strip --nm=aarch64-linux-android-nm --extra-libs='-L/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib
-lndk_compat' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon I/flutter (19889):   libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100 I/flutter
(19889):   libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100 I/flutter (19889):
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100 I/flutter (19889):
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100 I/flutter (19889):
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100 I/flutter (19889):   libswscale
1.100 /  7.  1.100 I/flutter (19889):   libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100 I/flutter (19889): Input #0, png_pipe, from
'/data/user/0/com.example.poc_stream/cache/frame.png': E/flutter
(19889): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
Exception: PlatformException(SESSION_NOT_FOUND, Session not found.,
null, null) E/flutter (19889): #0
StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
(package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7) E/flutter
(19889): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18) E/flutter
(19889):  E/flutter (19889): #2
FFmpegKitFactory.mapToNullableSession
(package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/src/ffmpeg_kit_factory.dart:76:3)
E/flutter (19889):  E/flutter (19889): #3
FFmpegKitInitializer._processCompleteCallbackEvent.
(package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/src/ffmpeg_kit_flutter_initializer.dart:213:48)
E/flutter (19889):  E/flutter (19889):
I/flutter (19889):   Duration:  I/flutter (19889): N/A I/flutter
(19889): , bitrate:  I/flutter (19889): N/A I/flutter (19889):
I/flutter (19889):   Stream #0:0 I/flutter (19889): : Video: png,
rgba(pc), 412x771 I/flutter (19889): ,  I/flutter (19889): 25 fps,
I/flutter (19889): 25 tbr,  I/flutter (19889): 25 tbn I/flutter
(19889):  E/flutter (19889):
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
Exception: PlatformException(SESSION_NOT_FOUND, Session not found.,
null, null) E/flutter (19889): #0
StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
(package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7) E/flutter
(19889): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18) E/flutter
(19889):  E/flutter (19889): #2
FFmpegKitFactory.mapToNullableSession
(package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/src/ffmpeg_kit_factory.dart:76:3)
E/flutter (19889):  E/flutter (19889): #3
FFmpegKitInitializer._processCompleteCallbackEvent.
(package:ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/src/ffmpeg_kit_flutter_initializer.dart:213:48)
E/flutter (19889):  E/flutter (19889):
I/flutter (19889): yzsFZWrI_Iw I/flutter (19889): currentBc:
yzsFZWrI_Iw I/flutter (19889): Stream mapping: I/flutter (19889):
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 I/flutter (19889):  (png (native) -> h264
(libx264)) I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889): Press [q] to stop,
[?] for help I/flutter (19889): Stream mapping: I/flutter (19889):
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 I/flutter (19889):  (png (native) -> h264
(libx264)) I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889): Press [q] to stop,
[?] for help I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb4000073639665d0] using
cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @
0xb4000073639665d0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.0, 4:4:4,
8-bit I/flutter (19889): [libx264 @ 0xb4000073639665d0] 264 - core 164


H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2023 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3
deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0
deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6
lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
aq=1:1.00 I/flutter (19889): Output #0, flv, to
'rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/x7k6-grm1-z15w-tqb7-akrt': I/flutter
(19889):   Metadata: I/flutter (19889):     encoder         :
I/flutter (19889): Lavf60.3.100 I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889):
Stream #0:0 I/flutter (19889): : Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007),
yuv444p(tv, unknown/bt709/iec61966-2-1, progressive), 412x771, q=2-31
I/flutter (19889): ,  I/flutter (19889): 25 fps,  I/flutter (19889):
1k tbn I/flutter (19889):  I/flutter (19889):     Metadata: I/flutter
(19889):       encoder         :  I/flutter (19889): Lavc60.3.100
libx264 I/flutter (19889):


